# Is there a way to request an answer from a specific user?

Tags: support

I am fairly sure that there is exactly one person on this site who can answer [the MERP question i just posted](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/86624/23970), due to it being about a fairly obscure game system. Is there any way to get in touch with that user specifically?

Comment: Related: [Can I send a private message...](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1274/23970)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 1. Leave a comment on any of their posts.

This will give them a little notification in their Inbox and, if your comment is sufficiently well-crafted, may motivate them to help you. A particularly useful comment to leave would be one requesting that person join you in chat.

### 2. "ping" them in a chat room.

*If* that user's been in a chat room recently you can "ping" them by addressing them directly in a message. Type `@` and the beginning of their username--if it autocompletes then that user's been in the room recently enough to be "pingable."

Comment: This was a lot more helpful of an answer than i expected to get from anyone off this question. Thank you very much!